# Getting inverse of a transposition key

Tags: transposition-cipher

I'm new to security stuff and I have some questions about the keys of transposition cryptography.

If I'm given the encoding key to a transposition cipher, how do I get the decoding key for it? I tried googling but couldn't find any steps on the calculation for it. For example, on several crypto-related websites there are these nifty tools where, when I enter `4 3 1 6 2 5` I would get `3 5 2 1 6 4`… but *why* and *how*?

Answer (score 2):

The key is obtained by taking the encryption steps in reverse.
For example, let's encrypt the word "United" with that `4 3 1 6 2 5` key. 
The first step is to take the 4th letter, a "t" and make it the first.
In the decryption, this first ciphertext letter must go to the 4th place again.
So the fourth step in the decryption, must be to look at what is in the first position - a "t" - and put that back in the fourth place again. Indeed we see in the decryption key that "1" is the value its fourth member.
By continuing these steps, you can derive the inverse key.

Here is a little code snippet that does the calculation.

```
static int[] inverse_key( int[] key )
{
    int[] inverse_key = new int[ key.length ];
    for ( int i = 0; i < key.length; i++ )
    {
        inverse_key[ key[ i ] - 1 ] = i + 1;
    }
    return inverse_key;
}
```

The "-1" and "+1" in the code are because arrays in most programming languages are 0-based; they do not relate to the actual algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

This is more a **permutation cipher** rather than a *transposition one*.

About the principle if in your key you have :

```
   ENCRYPTION
position -- key
   1         4
   2         3
   3         1
   4         6
   5         2
   6         5
```

So considering a 6 input block : `a b c d e f`, you would have :
`a` goes to the 4th position.
`b` goes to the 3rd position...
and so on.
This would result on : `c e b a f d`.

Now if you want to inverse this transformation, (`c e b a f d` $\mapsto$ `a b c d e f`).

Then you can see that :
`c` goes to the 3rd position.
`e` goes to the 5th position...
and so on...

Which gives you :

```
   Decryption
position -- key
   1         3
   2         5
   3         2
   4         1
   5         6
   6         4
```

Given numbers only, how to produce the decryption key ?

1. Reverse the columns

   ```
       ENCRYPTION           DECRYPTION
   position -- key   =>   position -- key
      1         4           4         1
      2         3           3         2 
      3         1           1         3
      4         6           6         4
      5         2           2         5
      6         5           5         6
   ```
2. Reorder the positions list on the Decryption part.

   ```
       DECRYPTION           DECRYPTION
   position -- key   =>   position -- key
      4         1           1         3
      3         2           2         5 
      1         3           3         2
      6         4           4         1
      2         5           5         6
      5         6           6         4
   ```

---

A bit of formalism (which was lacking) :

You need to make sure that $\forall i, D(E(i)) = i$ where $E$ is the encryption and $D$ the decryption.
Lets consider the case where $i$ is $1$, hence we have $E(1)=3$
Let's replace in our previous equation : $D(E(1)) = 1 \iff D(3) = 1$
Therefore during the decryption $3 \mapsto 1$ 
By doing so with the other $i$ you can construct your decryption key.

And yes the inverse function is build in a similar way as for a substitution cipher.

Answer (score -2):

Let $E_i$ be the transposition cipher associated with the first encryption, and $D_i$ associated with the second one. You only need to garantee that $D_{E_i}=i, \forall i$. Now let's see the magic happening:

$E_3=1$ and $D_1=3$.

Wooow it works!

Comment: Please be nice to other peoples, not sarcastic. And your formalism isn't the easiest way to understand how it works.